# How to hide EA properties dialog?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using EA Api's "EA_OnPostNewElement" to modify the dropped element from the Toolbox. As soon I drop the element from the toolbox to the diagram, EA properties diaglog is popped up. Even after using

```
Repository.SuppressEADialogs = true;
```

How to suppress the EA diaglog if any Element is dropped from the toolbox ?

Comment: make sure you are setting that property as soon as the event is fired, if it still doesn't work, I'd count it as a bug, and an important one at that

Comment: You might need to post the event here in case you're doing something you shouldn't we could point out

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might have to return true in the event code after if you don't want the properties dialog to appear( returning true informs EA that you have processed  the creation of the element)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_oncontextitemdoubleclicked.html) says indeed to use `Repository.SuppressEADialogs = true;` to disable the standard properties dialog to show up.
If that doesn't work you should probably send in a bug report.

But you can also disable that from the general options by disabling the option `Objects | Edit Object on New`

Then use the event [EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_oncontextitemdoubleclicked.html) to show your own properties dialog and return `true` to let EA know that you have handled the double-click event so it doesn't show the default properties dialog anyway.